# Antlr4 compiler PyCharm Plugin produces incorrect Python3 code. Is this a bug or an operator error?

Tags: python, parsing, pycharm, antlr4

I am compiling the https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr/antlr4/examples/CPP14.g4 grammar  (I renamed the grammar file to C.g4 and changed the first line in the grammar file to `grammar C;`)

**Summary:**

- C.g4 grammar compiles without error in the Tool Output within the PyCharm IDE
- CParser.py file (output from antr4 -o command) has an incorrect python line of code on line 15273

  `if((None if localctx.val is None else localctx.val.text).compareTo("0")!=0) throw new InputMismatchException(this);`
- Is this a known bug?

**Details:**

From within the PyCharm IDE.

[image]

```
Ctrl-Shift+G
```

The produces no error on the Tool Output window:

`2024-01-17 20:59:43: antlr4 -o C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Git\GitHub\c2p-antlr4\gen -listener -visitor -Dlanguage=Python3 -lib C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Git\GitHub\c2p-antlr4 C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Git/GitHub/c2p-antlr4\C.g4`

---

The generated code has an error as shown in the CParser.py code below:

[image]

Notice line 15273. I discovered the error when trying to run the parser on a code file. The line is hit while using the parser.

**This isn't valid Python code!!  Has anyone seen this issue and/ or is there a fix for this?**

The plugin I'm using is version 1.22:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[That grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr/antlr4/examples/CPP14.g4) has 1 piece of target specific code on line 1093:

```java
{if($val.text.compareTo("0")!=0) throw new InputMismatchException(this);}
```

which seems to be Java code. Either remove it, or change it to Python:

```py
{if $val.text != "0": raise Exception('Oops!')}
```

and try again.